# How to use user input in Cluster(Node JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, multiprocessing

Am trying to get an input in the main thread than use it in the working threads
so I have this code

```
Multi_processing = async() => {
if (cluster. IsMaster) {
    const name = await prompt(' input '); 
    
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
    for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) {
      cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
      console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} finished`);
    });
  } 
    else {
 
    console.log(name)
       
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
  }
}
```

when I try to get the input from outside the function it get the input as many the as the process which I don't want to input once to save up time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [Thomas Sablik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4645334/thomas-sablik) Previous answer you can  get the input in this way

```
Multi_processing = (() => {
  return async () => {
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
      let name = prompt("ask")
      
      console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
      for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cluster.fork({  name : name  });
      }
      cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} finished`);
      });
    } else {
     
      console.log(process.env.name);

    }
  };
})();
```